# Python AttributeError in using a member variable

Tags: python

I am having an issue with Python throwing an AttributeError on accessing a variable.

The code is below, redacted for clarity.

```
class mycollection(object):
    """
    Collection of stuff. 
    """
    #"compile-time" define class variables.
    __slots__ = ["stuff_list"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff_list = []

    def add_stuff(self, stuff):
        self.stuff_list.append(stuff)


#later on..
collection = mycollection()
stuff = stuff()
collection.add_stuff(stuff)
```

Generating this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "", line 206, in main
    thestuff = load_file(inputfile, filetype)
  File "pyyft.py", line 121, in load_file
    collection.add_stuff(stuff)
  File "pyyft.py", line 55, in add_test
    self.stuff_list.append(stuff)
AttributeError: stuff_list
```

Checking through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references), I don't understand why this error is arising.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you must (err, probably) have the string "test_stuff". Please post that code.

Comment: Fixed typo in `__init__` - if you copied/pasted that, you may want to fix it in the source.  Also, any particular reason you're using `__slots__`?

Comment: @Jed - yeah, I am avoiding autovivification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__ini__` should be `__init__`

Comment: Durp. Accept incoming when the timer OK's me to.

Comment: I see that Jed Smith has edited the question, but I suspect that is the cause.

Comment: could someone explain to me how `test_stuff` and `stuff_list` are related?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be "more Pythonic"?

collection.stuff_list.append(test_stuff)

Comment: It's not Pythonic to twiddle about with the internal state of objects, just because you can.

Comment: I don't grasp the entirety of the idea of 'pythonic', but I do know that what you propose presents a leakage of information between the object and the scope the object lives in. Put another way, it increases code coupling between modules. Put another way, it breaks OO paradigm. However you call it, it makes code maintenance and evolution more difficult.